# How to annotate facets but not margins in ggplot2

Tags: r, annotations, ggplot2, facet

How do I uniquely annotate each main facet, but with no annotation in the corresponding margin facets?  The following code places the text in the main facets how I'd like, but the margins show the texts superimposed.  How do I suppress the text in the margin facets?

```
frame_labels <- data.frame(
  frame = LETTERS[1:4],
  vs = rep(0:1, each = 2),
  am = rep(0:1, times = 2),
  x = 5, y = 33)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
p <- p + facet_grid(vs ~ am, margin = TRUE, as.table = FALSE)
p <- p + geom_text(data = frame_labels, aes(x = x, y = y, label = frame))
print(p)
```

Comment: You might need to preprocess the dataset if you want to do this.  See Winston's answer on [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ggplot2/3pomgBPRmyo/2vZnZ4Igc3IJ).

Comment: Thanks @aosmith, I saw that thread but I don't understand it.  I interpreted it to mean add an extra level to the faceting variables called "ALL" to the geom_text data.frame.  I couldn't get any of several things that seemed consistent with his comment to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on [the thread I mentioned in a comment](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ggplot2/3pomgBPRmyo/2vZnZ4Igc3IJ) was that you had to essentially get the "margins" into your dataset.  I am sure there is an elegant way to do this, but it is escaping me at the moment.  Here is a "brute force" method that seems to work, but isn't pretty.

Essentially I make three extra copies of the dataset and add a third level to `vs` and `am` to incorporate the margins.  Then I `rbind` 'em all together.  At first I thought it wasn't working, but I realized I needed to change the level order for `vs` so the reverse order matches the order in your example.  Then your dataset `frame_labels` works like a charm to add the labels.

```
mtcars2 = mtcars3 = mtcars4 = mtcars
mtcars2$vs = mtcars3$am = mtcars4$am = mtcars4$vs = "all"
mtcarsall = rbind(mtcars, mtcars2, mtcars3, mtcars4)

mtcarsall$vs = factor(mtcarsall$vs, levels = c("all", "0", "1"))

ggplot(mtcarsall, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(vs ~ am, as.table = FALSE)+
    geom_text(data = frame_labels, position = NULL, aes(x = x, y = y, label = frame))
```

Comment: Awesome! Brute force or not, it gets the job done. Big Thanks @aosmith!

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the geom_text(...) part.

Code should look like this to have the desired output

```
library(ggplot2)

frame_labels <- data.frame(
frame = LETTERS[1:4],
vs = rep(0:1, each = 2),
am = rep(0:1, times = 2),
x = 5, y = 33)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
p <- p + facet_grid(vs ~ am, margin = TRUE, as.table = FALSE)
print(p)
```

Hope this helps.